# Why $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Refer to Heine-Borel theorem, since $\mathbb R$ is a vector space of finite dimension, all closed and bounded of $\mathbb R$ should be compact. Here $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded, therefore it should be compact, no ? But it's not and I don't understand why.

Comment: Probably best to state your version of Heineken Borel, because you seem to be using one I’ve never heard of.

Comment: Sorry; didn’t read title properly. I’ll blame mobile.

Comment: In metric spaces compactness is the same as sequential compactness (i.e. every sequences has a convergent subsequence). Now look at the sequence 1,2,3..., the natural numbers. Would this sequence have a convergent subsequence in your new metric space? (Hint, if $L$ is a limit to some subsequence, notice that $|n-L|$ are infinitely often greater than 1, for any natural number.)

Comment: The set of open subsets in your space are actually the same as the open sets under the usual topology.

Answer (score 5):

The Heine-Borel theorem says that $\mathbb{R}^n$, **equipped with the Euclidean distance**,  has the given property.
The statement remains true if the Euclidean distance is replaced with an equivalent distance. Unfortunately, your distance is not equivalent to the Euclidean one.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much, it's clear now.

Comment: Actually, it is.

Comment: @G.Ottaviano: No, the distance is not equivalent to the Euclidean one. It gives you the same open sets (and hence the same topology), sure, but not so for bounded sets (since there are sets that are bounded under this metric but not in the usual one).

Comment: @psmears "It gives you the same open sets (and hence the same topology)" is exactly what I mean by they are equivalent.

Comment: Unfortunately, the definition of "equivalent" metric is not universal. Anyway, I mean that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent metrics if there exist positive constants $c_1, c_2$ such that $c_1 \, d_1 \leq d_2 \leq c_2 d_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The teorem you are refering to apply to finite dimension Banach space (which turns out they can only be $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ with any norm - since they are all equivalent)

In this case the metric you are using does not induce a norm, simply because for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $d(x,0) \leq 1$. (for a detailed proof of this just ask me in the comment)

Now, in your case simply 
$$
\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x \in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}} B \left(x,  \frac{3}{4} \right)
$$
which prove that your space is not compact

Comment: please explain how the union proves noncompactness